# enviar archivo y variable por POST - AJAX

Tags: ajax

Buen día,

Quería preguntar sobre como enviar un archivo y una variable al mismo tiempo, esto me funciona perfectamente solo con el archivo, lo que esta comentado es lo que yo intento hacer para la variable

// de aquí para arriba tengo una variable llamada nuevo_id que la obtuve con otro AJAX y si estoy seguro que esta bien por que al hacer un alert me imprime la variiable que quiero.... igual esto no viene al caso el como la obtuve

//aqui el script

```
var inputFileCedula = document.getElementById('archivoCedula');

            var file = inputFileCedula.files[0];
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('archivo',file);
            var url = 'php/subir_cedula.php';

            $.ajax
            ({  
                url:url,
                type:'POST',
                contentType:false,
                data:data, nuevo_id, //intenté poner una , y ahí la variable
                processData:false,
                cache:false
            });

-----------------------------------------------
aqui el archivo subir_cedula.php

<?php
    require 'conectar_bd.php';

    $nuevo_id2= $_POST['nuevo_id']; //intenté esto para recibir la variable


    $return = Array('ok'=>TRUE);

    $consulta = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `solicitudes`(`id`) VALUES ('$nuevo_id2')") or die ('Error. '. mysql_error()); // aqui usaré mencionada variable, pero al ejecutarse asi como lo muestro me guarda un cero, debe ser no la estoy enviando bien

// de aqui para abajo todo funciona correctamente

    $upload_folder ='../archivos_subidos';
    $nombre_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    $tipo_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
    $tamano_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
    $tmp_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $archivador = $upload_folder . '/' . $nombre_archivo;

    if (!move_uploaded_file($tmp_archivo, $archivador)) {

    $return = Array('ok' => FALSE, 'msg' => "Ocurrio un error al subir el archivo. No pudo guardarse.", 'status' => 'error');
    }

    echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

alguna idea?

gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Si ya estás usando un `FormData()` para la imagen entonces ingresa el resto de valores que quieres enviar a ese mismo objeto de formulario

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('archivo',file);
data.append('nuevo_id',nuevo_id);
data.append('otro_ejemplo',otro_ejemplo);

 $.ajax
    ({  
        url:url,
        type:'POST',
        contentType:false,
        data:data,
        processData:false,
        cache:false
    });
```

Y así sucesivamente dependiendo de cuantas variables debas enviar.

Espero que te sirva, saludos !

Comment: Excelente! gracias mi hermano

Comment: Si la respuesta sirvió para tu solución te invito a que marques la respuesta como aceptada para que los futuros desarrolladores sepan que fue una solución correcta al problema y lo puedan implementar. Me alegra que te sirviera, Saludos !